# How to fix IF/ELSE statments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create an authorization process and it always says name unauthorized, despite the name not being assigned to the unauthorized variable.

I've tried different organization of the code, ie different order, but the problem hasn't improved.

```
Tessa=str
un = Tessa
n1=str
n2=str
input(n1("What is the name of player one?"))
if n1 == un:
    print("Name unauthorised, try again")
else:
    print ("Name authorised")
    input(n2("What is the name of player two?"))
    if n2 == un:
        print("Name unauthorised, try again")
    else:
        print("Name authorised")
        print("Welcome")
```

I expect any inputted name other than Tessa to result in the phrase "Name authorized" but instead it prints the unauthorized message."

Comment: Hi, you must be new to python. There are many things wrong with the code that you've presented. I assume you intend to do type assignments with `n1=str`, which is not a thing in python. Are you intending `Tessa` to be a string value? You need to actually assign it as a string, like this: `un = "Tessa"`

Comment: ```n1 = str```. ???

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the statements `n1 = str`. Please check my code.

```
un = 'Tessa'

n1 = input("What is the name of player one?")
if n1 == un:
    print("Name unauthorised, try again")
else:
    print ("Name authorised")

    n2 = input("What is the name of player two?")
    if n2 == un:
        print("Name unauthorised, try again")
    else:
        print("Name authorised")
        print("Welcome")
```

and the result will be as below.

```
What is the name of player one? lam
Name authorised
What is the name of player two? rio
Name authorised
Welcome
```

Answer (score 1):

you're clearly new to Python, so here are some things that you should fix:

- Python doesn't need variables to have certain type. There is no need for what you were intending with `n1 = str`.
- If you want to assign an actual string value, you can do so using quotes: `"my string value"`.
- If you want to do repeated checks, do it as part of a loop
- If you want to store multiple values, use a list. (like for player names)
- If you might have multiple values to check against (you might have multiple unauthorised names), use a list.

In light of these, consider the following code snippet:

```
unauthorised_names = ["Tessa"]

player_names = []

while len(player_names) < 2:
    name = input("Please enter a name for player {}:".format(len(player_names) + 1))
    if name in unauthorised_names:
        print("Unauthorised name, please try again")
    else:
        player_names.append(name)

print(player_names)
```

Here `unauthorised_names` holds every name that cannot be entered. It can be one, it can be many.

`player_names` contain the names of the players.

You run it, until you got a sufficient number of valid player names, with the `while` loop

You take the input, with the number of the player as a parameter

Check it if it's on the list of invalid names, and store it, if it isn't.

Once you have the right number of names, you proceed with your program.

[Try it for yourself!](https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user304_vfV3Ay8BxI_1.py)

Answer (score 0):

To take an input and keep the value in `n1`, you need to do this:

`n1 = str(input("What is the name of player one?"))`

Also, I have no idea where you're going with the `n1 = str`, etc., so I suggest you scrap it.